# What is Bootstrap 4 Form Validation novalidate for?

Tags: validation, bootstrap-4

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
```

Why do we need to put **novalidate**? It makes a different if it is pure Html 5, but I failed to notice any differences in bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

`novalidate` prevents the browser's automatic validation kicking in and checking the form (like making sure that a field with type `number` is actually a number, and so on).

`.needs-validation` lets the Bootstrap JavaScript know that the form needs the JS to validate it.

So, together, `novalidate` stops the browser validating the form, and `.needs-validation` asks Boostrap JS to validate the form instead.

Comment: Precisely, but I find no differences with / without **novalidate** when bootstrap **.needs-validation** is added. That I why I am wondering if it is actually needed.

Comment: I’m not sure then. It might make a difference depending on what browser you’re using, or just be considered good practice to explicitly disable default functionality when implementing custom handling.